# JavaScript: execute code in a specific context

Tags: javascript, selenium, scope

How I can execute a JavaScript function/piece of code in a specific context which it would see as a global context? This is not the same as changing this (call/apply), this is more like changing 'window'.

Basically, if I have the following code:

```
(function() { x.value = 5; return value; })()
```

is there a way to make it work (return 5) without changing the code itself?

Also, executing code in the context of x (if possible) is my first idea, but maybe there is some other solution as well?

**UPDATE:**

Original problem: I am trying to test a bookmarklet using selenium. Bookmarklet assumes that it can do

```
window.SomeObject = {...}; SomeObject.doSomething();
```

I get the bookmarklet from the page and execute it using $selenium.get_eval, and in context of get_eval global object is some object of selenium itself, not the window. `window.SomeObject` still works because selenium context has window, but just `SomeObject` does not work.

I think I know another possible solution, but I would like to know if there is an answer to original question.

**UPDATE 2 (solution):**

Final solution (based on answer by geowa4):

```
x = {}; with(x) { return (function() { x.value = 5; return value; })(); }
```

Comment: could you please explain what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: First of all, you're setting `x.value` but returning just `value`, so your code *won't* "return 5". Second of all, what?

Comment: added explanation to the end of the post

Comment: @crescentfresh it will if x === window, for example (in normal browser context)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your scope using the `with` keyword.

```
(function() { x.value = 5; with(x) { return value; })();
```

The `with` keyword scopes the block of code to the given object. So in this case, you will return 5.

Comment: @crescentfresh: yeah, but that's impossible so i went with the closest option. a bit of a stab in the dark.

Comment: I have added more details to the question. With is a very good idea, but will it work in outer scope? I'll check.

Comment: You rule. x = {}; with(x) { var result = (function() { x.value = 5; return value; })(); alert(result); } works perfectly!